# Inheriting from System.Data.Common.DbCommand, Parameters property is null

Tags: c#, system.data

I'm busy building a custom framework for data retrieval and serialization and I'm running into a problem when defining a proprietary database connection/command/parameter combo. Everything works as expected until I try and add parameters to my custom command object. I have a base class that handles query preparation and execution with a generic function as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Prepares a command for execution.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="C">The type of command to prepare</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="P">The type of parameters to add to the command</typeparam>
/// <param name="query">The query to be prepared for the command</param>
/// <param name="parameters">Dictionary of parameters to be added to the command</param>
/// <returns>A prepared command to execute against a database</returns>
protected virtual C Prepare<C, P>(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    where C : DbCommand, new()
    where P : DbParameter, new()
{
    if (Connection == null)
        throw new System.Exception("Database connector hasn't been initialized yet. Call .Initialize() first.");
    C command = new C()
    {
        CommandText = query,
        Connection = Connection
    };
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new P() // <-- Breaks right here!
            {
                ParameterName = kvp.Key,
                Value = kvp.Value
            });
        }
        parameters = null;
    }
    return command;
}
```

I have classes implemented for most of the provider types (Ole, ADO, ODBC, Oracle, etc), but they are based off the standard .NET types provided in the `System.Data` namespace. I now have a completely custom class that inherits from `System.Data.Common.DbCommand` that I want to use, but when I try and add parameters (in the `Prepare` function above) to this new class, I see the `Parameters` property of my new class is `null`! It is inherited from the base class and is set to read only, so I can't initialize it on my own. My class is defined as follows:

`public sealed class Connection : System.Data.Common.DbConnection`

I've tried explicitly overriding the property in my class as `public new List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }` but to no avail - the generic function still uses the base class' `Parameters` property. The only way to get a handle on the overridden property is to explicitly cast `command` (in the `Prepare` function) to my custom type, which is obviously what I don't want to do.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `new` doesn't override the parameter, it's hiding it. This means that anyone using DbCommand.Parameters will see the original implementation while anyone using your type will see your implementation.

Overriding a property can only be done using the `override` keyword. In this case, you can't override `Parameters` because it isn't virtual.

Second, `DbCommand.Parameters` is just an external interface over the `protected abstract` [DbCommand.DbCommandParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.dbparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You need to implement this method to return a actual parameter collection.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for that... I managed to sort the issue shortly after I posted the question. I didn't see your answer before I posted my own, but I'll accept yours as correct, just because it was exactly what I ended up doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to sort out the issue. Can't believe I've been blind to this the whole morning! When implementing a new class that inherits from `System.Data.Common.DbCommand` you have to override the `DbParameterCollection` property, among others. In my haste to create the new class I just returned `null` in the getter of this property and, I assume, that's what the `Parameters` property uses.

So I just implemented a new class that inherits from `System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection` and returned a new instance of that class in my getter and it's working now!